# get all elements by class name of text boxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have a few text boxes on my javascript page with the class of textID.  So if I were to do

```js
function UpdateTotals() {
    getText = document.getElementsByClassName('textID').value;
}
```

All of the values will be numbers, so how do I add all of the values in this class together?  Example:  there are 4 text boxes, each one has the number 2 in it.  I want to get 8 by adding them all together (but only the text boxes that are in that class).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One example could be using [**Array.prototype.reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const textID = document.querySelectorAll('.textID');
const total = [...textID].reduce((a, el) => a + (+el.textContent.trim()), 0);

console.log(total);   // 8
```

```html
<div class="textID">2</div>
<div class="textID">2</div>
<div class="textID">2</div>
<div class="textID">2</div>
```

For INPUT elements:

```js
const textID = document.querySelectorAll('.textID');
const total = [...textID].reduce((a, el) => a + (+el.value), 0);

console.log(total);   // 8
```

```html
<input class="textID" type="number" value="2">
<input class="textID" type="number" value="2">
<input class="textID" type="number" value="2">
<input class="textID" type="number" value="2">
```

Using [**NodeList.forEach()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

```js
const textID = document.querySelectorAll('.textID');
let total = 0;

textID.forEach(el => total += +el.value);

console.log(total);   // 8
```

```html
<input class="textID" type="number" value="2">
<input class="textID" type="number" value="2">
<input class="textID" type="number" value="2">
<input class="textID" type="number" value="2">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

**HTML code:**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="textID" name="qty" value="2"/> 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="textID" name="qty" value="2"/> 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="textID" name="qty" value="2"/> 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="textID" name="qty" value="2"/> 2<br>
<br><br>
Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>

<a href="javascript:sumInputs()">Sum</a>
```

**JS code:**

```
window.sumInputs = function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('textID'),
        result = document.getElementById('total'),
        checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="qty"]:checked`),
        sum = 0;
        
    for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
        var ip = inputs[i];
    
        if (ip.name && ip.name.indexOf("total") < 0) {
            sum += parseInt(ip.value) || 0;
        }
    
    }
    
    result.value = sum;
}
```

Try it in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/u62tyj45/

Comment: Don't bloat the Global (`window`) scope, and don't use inline JavaScript. JS should be in one place only, and that's your Script file or tag. Also, why the use of `ip.name`? You already collected all the elements you were interested in by using `var inputs`

Comment: Also, why than two lines after create a `inputs` variable? You already have the `inputs` one.  `checkboxes.length` and than missing labels, name="" would be better different... those are not radio buttons.... Anyways, here's your improved idea: https://jsfiddle.net/8eL9jafo/